# Constructing a string for SQL "IN" for Google Fusion Tables

Tags: javascript, sql, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Fusion table full of country names and their corresponding geodata. I have a site in place that needs to take an array of country names and put them into the SQL `IN('foo', 'bar', 'baz')` as part of the string I set for adding layers to my Google Map.

Here is an example of code that *does* work:

```
var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
        select: 'geometry',
        from: '1vnD6W9q3VWvV3UFaza8I8UwSSWv5k6kemDjNYLo',
        where: 'CNTRYNAME IN(\'Tanzania\', \'Angola\')'
    },
    styles: [{
        polygonOptions: {
        fillColor: "#D77D00",
        fillOpacity: 0.4
    },
    markerOptions: {
        iconName: 'open_diamond'
    },
}],
});
layer.setMap(map);
```

You will notice that the query string requires the `\` for the array that SQL needs for the `IN` values. I'm completely stuck on how to construct a string from an array of values that needs to go in there.

Here's what I've tried:

```
var str = 'CNTRYNAME IN(';
for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
    str += '\\\'' + countries[i] + '\\\'';
    }
str += ')';
```

The query no longer works correctly in this case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the escaping of the quotes, you can simply use here:

```
str += "'" + countries[i] + "'";
```

The problem is that you ommit the commas inside the query.

This should work:

```
var str = "CNTRYNAME IN('"+countries.join("','")+"')";
```

Comment: Had to remove that last closed paren, but then it worked! Thanks